# Drupal Views based on filtering taxonomies based on available content

Tags: drupal, view, filtering, taxonomy

This seems like it should be relatively basic, but I can't seem to wrap my brain around it. I have a client in need of some advanced filtering for thousands of different content items. Each content item will be filed using different taxonomy types. As you filter through the system, it should eliminate content that does not correspond to the selected taxonomy.

So far, so good.

The issue is that the filters should update based on taxonomy of the selected content.

In this particular case, there's a select box for Location, Hunting/Fishing, and Species. If they select Illinois > Fishing > Freshwater, the last filter (Species) should only show tags from the Species list that correspond to previously selected filters.

The system works fabulously already but displays every species of fish, not just the ones from the selected filter.

Any guidance would be tremendously appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend [Views_Hacks](https://drupal.org/project/views_hacks) module for this (*Views Selective Exposed Filters* submodule) as also as an AJAX enabled and Autosubmit views.

Comment: Beautiful! I haven't yet implemented it, but it looks like this is what I'm after. Thanks so much for the suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal facet search https://drupal.org/project/facetapi will give you the required functionality.

A quick search on google for 'faceted search drupal' will give you lots of tutorials on how to set it up, one of which being: http://envisioninteractive.com/drupal/drupal-7-views-with-faceted-filters-without-apachesolr/